# Feature Suggestion: Officially support Poll type questions

Tags: feature-request, polling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [We have Community wikis and normal questions; we need Polls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59247/we-have-community-wikis-and-normal-questions-we-need-polls)

(Yes, I'm prepared to be heavily down-voted ... I know that many here don't like poll questions for some reason)

I think that some poll type questions add much value to Stack Overflow, that I can't find anywhere else. I would like to see these types of questions officially supported as a first class citizen.

- Poll type questions should not earn any reputation (I guess they should behave like community wiki)
- A poster should be able to mark his question a poll.
- Every answer to a poll question must contain exactly one item. I think there should be a field besides the answer body that should include the name/URL of the answer.

Comment: Can we make it so when somebody submits a poll question it just automatically submits it to reddit instead?

Comment: @Michael - is reddit a good place to ask questions such as these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452385/what-java-orm-do-you-prefer-and-why

Comment: @rippe234 I'm not super active there, but I would think so; that seems like a perfect AskProggit question. If not, I'm sure there's a website somewhere dedicated to this exact thing

Comment: @Michael - to make your case, please point out some similar questions answered elsewhere on the internet. Also, explain why Stack Overflow isn't a good place for these kinds of questions. I think it is. I see no reason to make this distinction. In fact, I am tempted to make a poll question on Meta - "List of all good poll questions on SO" ... only I'm afraid it would get closed as subjective and argumentative. How about "List of all poll questions on SO with more than 20 upvotes?" That's objective enough, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not going to have the "poll questions on-topic?" debate in the comment thread of a closed question, it's been done dozens of times all over meta